# Bubble Sort with ellipse

Tags: processing, indexoutofboundsexception, bubble-sort

Goal:
I want to sort randomly generated ellipse to their radius. From Min -> Max.

Problem:
Every time i run, this a error occurs. `ArrayIndexOutOfBunds`.

Here is my Code:

```
Ellipse[] e = new Ellipse[100];
int j;
void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  for (int i = 0; i<e.length; i++) {
    e[i] = new Ellipse(random(10, width-10), height/2, random(10, 80), color(random(1, 255)));
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i<e.length; i++) {
    e[i].show();
  }
  if (j<e.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i<e.length-1; i++) {
      float a = e[i].r;
      float b = e[i+1].r;
      if (a>b) {
        swap( int(e[i].x), int(e[i+1].x));
      }
    }
  }
  j++;
}
void swap(int a, int b) {
  float zwischen = e[a].x;
  e[a].x = e[b].x;
  e[b].x = zwischen;
}
class Ellipse {
  float x, y, r;
  color c;
  Ellipse(float x_, float y_, float r_, color c_) {
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
    r = r_;
    c = c_;
  }
  void show() {
    fill(c);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to swap the element with the index `i` and the element with the index `i+1`. The function `swap` swaps 2 elements. The arguments to the function are the indices of the elements. So it has to be:

<s>`swap( int(e[i].x), int(e[i+1].x));`</s>

```java
swap(i, i+1);
```

To make the algorithm work the index of the ellipse in list has to correspond to the position of the ellipse along the x axis. If the x axis and the y axis is random, the ellipses would be sorted to random positions by its size. You what to sort the ellipses by its radius along the x axis.
Create the ellipses by ascending x coordinate with random radius:

```java
for (int i = 0; i<e.length; i++) {
    int x = 10 + (width-20) * i / e.length;
    e[i] = new Ellipse(x, height/2, random(10, 80), color(random(1, 255)));
}
```

Further more, `swap` has to swap the ellipses, but it has to keep the position along the x axis:

```java
void swap(int a, int b) {
    float ax = e[a].x;
    float bx = e[b].x;

    Ellipse temp = e[a];
    e[a] = e[b];
    e[b] = temp;

    e[a].x = ax;
    e[b].x = bx;
}
```

---

See the exmple:

[image]

```py
Ellipse[] e = new Ellipse[100];
int j=0;

void setup() {
    fullScreen();
    for (int i = 0; i<e.length; i++) {
        int x = 80 + (width-160) * i / e.length;
        e[i] = new Ellipse(x, height/2, random(10, 80), color(random(1, 255)));
    }
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    for (int i = 0; i<e.length; i++) {
       e[i].show();
    }

    if (j<e.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.length-1-j; i++) {
            float a = e[i].r;
            float b = e[i+1].r;
            if (a > b) {
              swap(i, i+1);
            }
        }
    }
    j++;
}

void swap(int a, int b) {
    float ax = e[a].x;
    float bx = e[b].x;

    Ellipse temp = e[a];
    e[a] = e[b];
    e[b] = temp;

    e[a].x = ax;
    e[b].x = bx;
}

class Ellipse {
    float x, y, r;
    color c;

    Ellipse(float x_, float y_, float r_, color c_) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
        r = r_;
        c = c_;
    }

    void show() {
        fill(c);
        ellipse(x, y, r, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working. Just randomly switching positions. :C